# Get only child nodes of anchor (a) type

Tags: javascript, object, child-nodes

I have this code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <a href=""><img src="some_url" /></a>
    <a href=""><img src="some_url" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <a href=""><img src="some_url" /></a>
    <a href=""><img src="some_url" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In js I have a variable which gets into JS object all the nodes of an "el" element:

```
var thumbElements = el.childNodes;
//display in console
console.log("thumbElements", thumbElements);
```

The element is tag of "container" class. Now, this object contains all the nodes including H4. How can I remove h4 and apply it only for an "a" elements only. I think I should find another method which gets only an "a" elements only rather then converting it in a loop, because I've noticed that in this object there are additional information like nextElementSibling, nextSibling, previousElementSibling, etc. so it's all connected.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you are trying to get. Are you after ALL A tags? Or only ones in a specific inner-container?

Answer (score 3):

Once you get your DOM element, which I am assuming is what "el" is, you can simply use the getElementsByTagName() method to get the anchors. This will return an array of elements matching the tagname supplied.

In your case it would be:

```
var anchors = el.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/d3fs7g05/1/